# Connecting to a sharded database from Java Application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, database-partitioning

I have some fundamental doubts regarding `database sharding` and connecting to a sharded database from a Java application.

After reading plenty of articles, currently I am left with an impression that the operation of sharding itself should be performed from database admininstration and should not be a responsibility of application developer. - Is this correct ?

My second question is bit parted.

If from a Java application I am trying to connect to a shadred database, then ultimately it comes down to the selection of different datasource ( per shard), and then performing CRUD operation against that.

Regarding this, I have found we can use Hibernate `Multi-tenancy` feature ( the `Separate database` way - considering sharding resulted into creating multiple databases).

The second way would be use Spring `AbstractRoutingDatasource` feature to dynamically determining the actual DataSource based on the current context.

Is the above assumption correct ?
Is there any other standard way to perform the task ?

Kindly consider this is a conceptual question, as I still have many doubts. Any leads is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> operation of sharding itself should be performed from database admininstration and should not be a responsibility of application developer. - Is this correct

This is correct. Moreover, the database client libraries and drivers handle the sharding logic behind the scenes, so the client does not need to know about it. As a developer you don't know if database is sharded or not (you will probably notice increased query time, but you don't handle sharding manually)

> If from a Java application I am trying to connect to a shadred database, then ultimately it comes down to the selection of different datasource ( per shard), and then performing CRUD operation against that.

Absolutely not, why do you want that? Let underlying balance loader decide what shard should be used for querying the data. For example, check this article: [Everything you need to know about DynamoDB Partitions](https://www.alexdebrie.com/posts/dynamodb-partitions/). DynamoDB has request router that handles sharding.

Hibernate Multi-Tenancy isn't used for sharding handling. Hibernate Multi-Tenancy is a feature that allows developers to use a single database instance to serve multiple tenants (clients or customers) with isolated data. In a multi-tenant environment, each tenant has their own separate data store, which means that data from one tenant cannot be accessed by another. Contrary to it all sharded data is meant to be accessible.

AbstractRoutingDataSource serves the same purpose as Hibernate Multi-Tenancy feature.

Comment: May thanks for your input. The 'request router' is still a service ( seems not out of the box). And if I am not using DynamoDB, I still need to build a service to determine the correct datasource.  

"Hibernate Multi-Tenancy isn't used for sharding handling." - You are right. I was thinking whether it is possible to use for sharding. Ultimately I need to determine the datasource from the 'tenantId' in request header. And this logic can be tweaked to suit my need. 

"data from one tenant cannot be accessed by another." - Right, but surely this can be handled within implementation.

Comment: "I still need to build a service to determine the correct datasource". Unless you are making diy database you don't need to it. Here is another example, mongoDB has it's own router too. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v3.0/core/sharded-cluster-query-router/#routing-process. Trying to create some kind of load balancer by yourself is good training and academic exercise, but you've better stick to existing solutions

Comment: Another example for sharded Postgres (Greenplum). There is a master host that is "entry to the Greenplum Database system, accepting client connections and SQL queries, and distributing work to the segment instances". You don't need to manually decide which replica/shard should be used: https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Tanzu-Greenplum/6/greenplum-database/GUID-admin_guide-intro-arch_overview.html#arch_master